# Update multiple views and multiple clients in ASP.NET MVC (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js, signalr

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with a Razor viewmodel. I want to implement SignalR with Knockout. Here is my code which is currently working perfectly.

I have a requirement that when a task is created it should display for all clients, and should also display client message on different view.

```
@model TaskManager.Models.TaskList
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

 <h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>TaskList</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Taskname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Taskname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Taskname)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Taskdesc)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Taskdesc)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Taskdesc)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
   </fieldset>
   }

  <div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>

  @section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  }
```

Comment: Your question does not include enough information to understand what you're truly asking for.  In fact, you don't even ask a real question, you just make some statements.

Comment: My question is when i create new task should be display notification to all users with task name and task description

Comment: I simply don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: 1.First Team Lead Create new task 2.Members side display new task details with signalr

Answer (score 1):

You may not be familiar with how SignalR works as this sounds like a homework assignment.  Forgive me if I am mistaken.

To start off, please read the wiki on SignalR: http://www.asp.net/signalr
Also, spend a little bit of time going through the tutorials on Knockout: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/.  This will help you get adjusted and familiar with how both technologies work and what their capable of.

Once ready to jump in, you will want to set up the server-side hub for SignalR.  Then, you can allow connections from client-side browsers through javascript.  Verify you can make a connection and communication between the server and clients both work great.  Go through both the SignalR wiki and sample projects if you feel stuck on anything.

Then, simply assign a javascript function to be callable by the server-side hub.  This function will update your Knockout view model for adding new tasks.

It's straightforward, but I do not have specific solution examples because I feel you have a some catching up to do.  Good luck on the assignment!